# Как вывести записи из рубрики на созданной странице из админ-панели Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Настроить вывод php кода из созданной страницы я научился. Смотрю документацию, не могу понять, как вывести последние записи из определенной рубрики? Если изменять page.php или index.php, то вывести получается. А если задача стоит, создать новую страницу то как я понял, нужно добавить какой-нибудь цикл вордпресс. Кто разбирается, помогите? Вот код вывода рубрики, который я нашел, но он не работает а созданной странице из админ-панели.

```html
<?php 
$args = array(
 'numberposts' => 3,
 'category' => 5,
 'post_status' => 'publish',
); 

$result = wp_get_recent_posts($args);

foreach( $result as $p ){ 
?>
 — <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($p['ID']) ?>"><?php echo $p['post_title'] ?></a><br />    
<?php 
} 
?>
```

Comment: Как вы соединяете приведённый код со страницей?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проще всего организовать вывод своим шорткодом. В админке на страницу добавьте текст такого вида:

```
[recent_posts category="my_cat" number="5"]
```

А в functions.php такой примерно код:

```
/**
 * Shortcode to output recent posts.
 *
 * @param array $atts Shortcode attributes.
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
function recent_posts_shortcode( $atts ) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'category'            => '',
        'number'              => -1,
        'order'               => 'DESC',
        'orderby'             => 'date',
        'tag'                 => '',
        'exclude_posts'       => '',
        'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
    ), $atts );

    $args = array(
        'category_name'       => $atts['category'],
        'showposts'           => $atts['number'],
        'order'               => strtoupper( $atts['order'] ),
        'orderby'             => $atts['orderby'],
        'tag'                 => explode( ',', $atts['tag'] ),
        'post__not_in'        => explode( ',', $atts['exclude_posts'] ),
        'ignore_sticky_posts' => $atts['ignore_sticky_posts'],
    );

    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $return_string = '<ul>';
        while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
            $query->the_post();
            $return_string .= '<li>';
            $return_string .= '<div class="ft-post-title"><a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></div>';
            $return_string .= '<div class="ft-post-date">' . get_the_date( 'j F Y' ) . '</div>';
            $return_string .= '<div class="ft-post-excerpt">' . get_the_excerpt() . '</div>';
            $return_string .= '<div class="ft-post-more"><a href="' . get_permalink() . '">Читать полностью</a></div>';
            $return_string .= '<div class="ft-post-big-date">' . get_the_date( 'j' ) . '</div>';
            $return_string .= '</li>';
        }
        $return_string .= '</ul>';
    } else {
        $return_string = 'Нет записей';
    }

    wp_reset_postdata();

    return $return_string;
}

add_shortcode( 'recent_posts', 'recent_posts_shortcode' );
```

Эта реализация принимает параметры, описанные в массиве $atts с указанными значениями по умолчанию.

Созданный шорткод можно использовать на любой странице, записи, виджете WordPress - практически где угодно.

Код рабочий, скопирован с одного из моих сайтов.